# npm packages not installing getting this error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
   https://npm.community

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #5:
>   Expected object but got string npm ERR! typeerror     at
>   inflatableChild (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:93:3)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at tryCatcher (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotValue (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotAccum (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.tryCatcher (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at _drainQueue (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as
>   _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>   npm ERR! typeerror     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
>   npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report
>   this error at: npm ERR! typeerror     https://npm.community
>
> node 12.6.0 npm 6.9.0

Comment: Please add the command(s) you used before getting this output.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use LTS version not current version. Right now LTS of node is `10.16.0` and the current version is `12.6.0`.

LTS tend to be more stable and have less bug because is stable version

Then when you installed is done try to run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then remove `package-lock.json`

Delete `node_modules` folder

Then run `npm i`

Comment: This work for me, thanks.(node: v8.14.1 npm: 6.4.1) while doing ```npm i @types/stompjs@2.3.3 --save-dev```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1- remove node_modules folder
2- npm cache clean --force
3- npm install