# Angular 8 localhost:4200 not found and "ng serve" not working

Tags: node.js, angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

NOT WORKING

An unhandled exception occurred:

> argument fn must be a function
>   See "C:\Users...." for further details.

And http://localhost:4200 not found .

How can I solve ?

Comment: do you have executed this command "npm install" ?

Comment: Please type `node -v` then `npm -v` and paste which versions you are using. That exception is probably related with your NodeJs version.

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928461/npm-packages-not-installing-getting-this-error/56928502#56928502)

Comment: node 12.6 , npm 6,9 , angular 8.1.1 on win7 @GhoulAhmed

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Same mistake not working

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2375 this will help you

Comment: In VS Code, using a Linux codespaces image, with Angular v17.0.6, this worked. It needed to create a virtual network:
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
  ➜  Network: http://172.16.5.4:4200/